# Filesystem type: MSDOS memory card

Tags: sd-card

I have a 32GB SD card, it's file system is MSDOS and I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am unable to delete anything from this card, even I can't format it.

Please someone help me out.

Comment: Is the write protect switch on?

Comment: @Zacharee1, no i have already checked it, it's not on.

Comment: Which program says that it's MSDOS? This shouldn't be an issue since that is how some programs detect FAT which is the default for SD cards. What's the device name (you can find it in gnome-disks)? What is the output of `lsblk -f /dev/device_name`? Have you tried scanning the filesystem with fsck (e.g. fsck.vfat)?

Comment: Is it mounted `rw` (read/write), or `ro` (read only)? Type `mount` and read the line for your device.  If it's `ro`, and not hardware disabled, you can `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/device_name /mount/point` (replace `/dev/device_name` and `/mount/point` with your values.

Comment: @LiveWireBT,  it's showing in properties of device, exactly written **Filesystem type: msdos**, and output of `lsblk -f/dev/sdb` is **NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb  vfat         58B3-A008                            /media/dayyanjd/58B3-A0081**

Comment: @waltinator,  The output of mount is `rw` for my device.